# cefsharp c# winforms wont refresh

Tags: c#, winforms, cefsharp

I'm trying out C# WinForms with CefSharp (installed via Nuget (VS 2017)) but I can't get the refresh button to do anything. I've tried different variations, but nothing.

I have effectively two browsers, one to our epos and one to our local system.  The forward and back buttons work okay between the two, but refresh doesn't do a damn thing.

This is what I have. I'm far from a coder so if anyone could point me in the right direction :-)

```
private void PictureBox5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (WFSbrowserkiosk != null)
        WFSbrowserkiosk.Refresh();
    if (WFSbrowservend != null)
        WFSbrowservend.Refresh();     
}
```

Comment: http://cefsharp.github.io/api/57.0.0/html/M_CefSharp_WebBrowserExtensions_Reload.htm

Comment: thanks, ive come across that one but cant get it to work?  where do i put it in relation to what i have?

Comment: Have a look closer at the API doc, you'll see it's an extension method and it's in the CefSharp namespace, so you'll need to add a using statement if you haven't already got one. If you still cannot get it working you'll need to include a more detailed code example and details of the error you are seeing.

Comment: thanks,  i do have the initialise higher up the page.  ive been trying to follow some tutorials and personally im impressed ive got it this far hahaha.  but not its getting not so straight forward.  there is also an issue with it loading certain things on the page poss java related or local storage that vend use maybe, but that'll be another post.

Comment: sorry, was trying to figure out how to sow the code as actual code...  not quick mastered it hahah

Comment: this is the top code `` public Form1() { InitializeComponent(); } public ChromiumWebBrowser WFSbrowservend; public ChromiumWebBrowser WFSbrowserkiosk; private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) { Cef.Initialize(new CefSettings()); WFSbrowserkiosk = new ChromiumWebBrowser("172.24.33.11:8080/kiosk"); WFSbrowservend = new ChromiumWebBrowser("vendhq.com/")‌​; }``

Comment: kind of getting there.  the page now refreshes but its refreshing both pages not just the one its on?
    ``private void PictureBox5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (WFSbrowserkiosk != null)
            {
                if (WFSbrowserkiosk.IsBrowserInitialized)
                    WFSbrowserkiosk.Reload();
            }
            if (WFSbrowservend != null)
            {
                if (WFSbrowservend.IsBrowserInitialized)
                    WFSbrowservend.Reload();
            }

        }
    ``